# Clojure binding not working

Tags: binding, jvm, clojure

I'm working through the Clojure examples in Stuart Halloway's "Programmming Clojure" and I've hit a snag when using binding:

```
(def foo 10)
; => '#user/foo

foo
; => 10

(binding [foo 42] foo)
; => 10

(binding [user/foo 42] foo)
; => 10

(binding [user/foo 42] (var-get #'user/foo))
; => 10
```

Why won't it give me 42?

Comment: In the second line, two characters seem to be switched.

Comment: What IDE / environment are you using?  What version of Clojure?  Your code works fine for me, latest Clojure from git, running from commandline.

Comment: Clojure-1.1.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT on Snow Leopard... I just tried it on my Windows PC on 1.0.0 and it worked fine, so it must be a bug with that version.  Funny thing is is that the book's author recommended that you use the bundled version of Clojure because he tested all his examples on it... and then it doesn't work for that example.

Comment: Same behavior on Linux/1.1.0-alpha, perhaps you should ask about this on http://groups.google.com/group/clojure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Verdict: bug

This appears to be a bug in the 1.1.0-alpha-SNAPSHOT and it is reproducible on Linux, too.

If you go back now to the Clojure d/l page, that version seems to have been withdrawn and 1.0.0 is the "Featured" d/l.

And in 1.0.0 your example does bind 42.

Answer (score 1):

On a related note:
 its really easy to be bitten by bindings in this way when ever you run code in another thread. I have encountered problems like this when a function I call evaluates something through `pmap` instead of  `map`  when the code is actually executed on a thread from the thread-pool. agents will do this also i believe.